# Problemas con las dimensiones de la leyenda en un gráfico al utilizar R-studio

Tags: r, rstudio

Con una serie de datos dibujo una línea de lo más simple en un gráfico.
[Datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ddd1vzrhz3bp5bg/data_c.csv?dl=0)

```
plot(x,fitted, col="blue",pch=18, ylim=c(0,3), type = 'l', ylab='entropy', xlab="level of content bias")
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, intento añadir una leyenda (siguiendo los pasos de la propia documentación) con tres niveles (da igual cuáles sean, es sólo para aprender):

```
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("1", "2", "3") , 
       lty=1, col=c('red', 'blue', "green"), cex=.75)
```

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Puede explicarme alguien por qué la leyenda aparece desproporcionadamente gigantesca y no agrupada en el margen inferior izquierdo? No he encontrado respuesta en ningún sitio.

Muchas gracias.

**Edición 1**

Hemos procedido a realizar algunos chequeos y hemos descartado que la incidencia descrita se deba a:

-Origen de los datos

-Versión de R

Posible interacción con R-Studio:

Al prescindir de R-studio y correr el código directamente utilizando la consola de R, la gráfica y leyenda aparecen correctamente. Por lo tanto, el problema parece deberse a algún tipo de interacción con R-studio.

No obstante, se ha procedido a descargar la última versión de R-studio y el problema persiste si se utiliza dicho software.

Estamos estudiando la salida de la función legend() para aportar una solución más cocnreta.

Comment: Mismo código con otra curva me funciona tal como se espera, el tema podría estar en los datos, puedes compartirlos?

Comment: Gracias. He subido los datos del ejemplo.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar, con esta regresión `lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data=df)` para luego calcular `fitted` me da una curva distinta, pero las leyendas se muestran bien.

Comment: Vaya expediente x. ¿Puedes probar con esta regresión? `nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), data = df)`

Comment: Ahora si obtengo tu misma curva, pero de todas formas la leyenda se ve bien, abajo a la izquierda y pequeña.

Comment: Lo que estoy observando es que con este modelo, `fitted` es un objeto que además tiene un atributo `gradient`, no sé si tiene que ver, pero por las dudas, prueba el plot haciendo un cast:  `as.vector(fitted)`.

Comment: No. Me sale idéntico. ¿Podría ser alguna actualización? Ni idea, me estoy volviendo loco :S

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75576/discussion-between-patricio-moracho-and-pyring).